# How to return data from post request in Node js?

Tags: node.js, post

I've tried to send a post request to an API
and I'm not able to get back the data to my async function ,
I've tried the next code:

```
function PostCode(codestring) {
  // Build the post string from an object
  var post_data = querystring.stringify({
      'compilation_level' : 'ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS',
      'output_format': 'json',
      'output_info': 'compiled_code',
        'warning_level' : 'QUIET',
        'js_code' : codestring
  });

  // An object of options to indicate where to post to
  var post_options = {
      host: 'closure-compiler.appspot.com',
      port: '80',
      path: '/compile',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(post_data)
      }
  };

  // Set up the request
  var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
          console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
          return chunk;
          });
      });

  // post the data
  post_req.write(post_data);
  post_req.end();

}
```

And in my async function the call of the function looks like that:

```
        let response = await PostCode(0);
```

The data is being printed well on that line:

```
  console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
```

But the return doesn't work at all

how can i return that 'chunk' variable safely to my main async function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a Promise when you want to use `await` and the Promise needs to resolve with your response.

```js
function PostCode(codestring) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Build the post string from an object
    var post_data = querystring.stringify({
      'compilation_level': 'ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS',
      'output_format': 'json',
      'output_info': 'compiled_code',
      'warning_level': 'QUIET',
      'js_code': codestring
    });

    // An object of options to indicate where to post to
    var post_options = {
      host: 'closure-compiler.appspot.com',
      port: '80',
      path: '/compile',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(post_data)
      }
    };

    //Store chunks
    var response = "";
    // Set up the request
    var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        response += chunk;
        console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
      });
      res.on('end', function() {
        //resolve on end event
        resolve(response);
      });
      res.on('error', function(error) {
        //reject on error event
        reject(error);
      });
    });

    // post the data
    post_req.write(post_data);
    post_req.end();
  });
}
```